# permission denied running check_vmfs.sh through NRPE

Tags: nagios, nrpe

we have a nagios monitoring system already running and I was after monitor our vmware datastores using the following [plugin](http://command[check_datastore_LocalSlot45S6]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_vmfs.sh%20-C%20/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/vmware_esxi_conf.txt%20-S%20192.168.20.241%20-V%20/vmfs/volumes/LocalSlot45S6%20-w%2075%20-c%2090%20-u%20Gb%20command[check_datastore_LocalSlot1-2S3]=/usr/)
I installed vmware cli and tested with no issues:

```
[root@nrpe-relay ~]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_vmfs.sh -C /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/vmware_esxi_conf.txt -S 192.168.20.241 -V /vmfs/volumes/LocalSlot45S6 -w 75 -c 90 -u Gb
WARNING - /vmfs/volumes/LocalSlot45S6 - total: 931.25 Gb - used: 800.95 Gb (86%)- free: 130.29 Gb (14%) | /vmfs/volumes/LocalSlot45S6=800.95Gb;698.43;838.12;;931.25

[root@nrpe-relay ~]# ps auxww|grep nrpe
nagios    1463  0.0  0.1  41468  1364 ?        Ss   21:24   0:00 nrpe -c /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg -d
root      2261  0.0  0.0 103304   876 pts/0    S+   22:00   0:00 grep nrpe
```

However I am not getting same value when the command runs remotely:

```
[root@nagios nagios]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H <hostname> -c 'check_datastore_LocalSlot45S6'
CRITICAL -
```

This is what I have in my cfg file

```
command[check_datastore_LocalSlot45S6]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_vmfs.sh -C /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/vmware_esxi_conf.txt -S 192.168.20.241 -V /vmfs/volumes/LocalSlot45S6 -w 75 -c 90 -u Gb
```

and my server cfg:

```
define service{
    use                     generic-service 
    host_name               <hostname>
    service_description     datastore-LocalSlot45S6
    check_command           check_nrpe!check_datastore_LocalSlot45S6
    }
```

This is what I can see from /var/log/message:

```
nagios nagios: EXTERNAL COMMAND: SCHEDULE_FORCED_SVC_CHECK;<hostname>;datastore-LocalSlot1-2S3;1441798845
```

QUESTION: Anyone has any clue about where the problem is? or how can I trace down this issue?

Comment: Firstly, who are you running `nrpe` as on the remote host?  You show that you can run the `check_vmfs.sh` on the remote host **as root**, but it is not likely that the NRPE daemon is running as root.  Paste the output of `ps auxww|grep nrpe` on the remote host into your answer.

Comment: @MadHatter, I have added that information in the question

Comment: So, we see it's running as user `nagios`.  What happens when you try to run `check_vmfs.sh` as the nagios user on nrpe-relay?

Comment: Try (as root) `/bin/su - nagios -s /bin/bash`, then run the full command from the shell.

Comment: @MadHatter /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_vmfs.sh: line 161: /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_vmfs.err: Permission denied
CRITICAL -

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the NRPE daemon runs as the user `nagios`, and that user doesn't have permission to run the command in question.

You will **either** have to open up permissions so that the user can run it (incidentally, your last comment suggests you're not paying complete attention to the output; it is the file `/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_vmfs.err` on which permission has been denied, not `check_vmfs.sh`), **or** modify the NRPEd to use passwordless sudo, with eg

```
command[check_datastore_LocalSlot45S6]=sudo /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_vmfs.sh -C /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/vmware_esxi_conf.txt -S 192.168.20.241 -V /vmfs/volumes/LocalSlot45S6 -w 75 -c 90 -u Gb
```

coupled with a `sudoers` entry similar to

```
nagios  ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_vmfs.sh
```

If you take the latter route, you will need also to have

```
Defaults    !requiretty
```

in your `sudoers` file, if it is not already there.

Comment: thank you mate, I just changed the file owner from root to nagios and that fixed the issue. thanks heaps for your quick response!